# How to parse json data comming from drupal site to android app?

Tags: android, json, drupal-7

I am trying to send data from drupal website to android app in the form of json. i have created the link and now my link is returning data in this form.
i don't have any idea how to parse this formatted data to show in a list view in android app.

```
{
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "node" : {
        "title" : "Saksham Iron Store",
        "Contact" : "09216630565",
        "Category" : "Decoration & Hardware",
        "City" : "Sangrur"
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "title" : "Loaffer Hut Garments",
        "Contact" : "8591697698",
        "Category" : "Fashion & Garments",
        "City" : "Sangrur"
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "title" : "BCB English Academy and Visa Guidance",
        "Contact" : "8699010091",
        "Category" : "Education",
        "City" : "Sangrur"
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "title" : "Aggarwal Engineering Corporation",
        "Contact" : "9417070197",
        "Category" : "Decoration & Hardware",
        "City" : "Sangrur"
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "title" : "Inder Sain Paint and Decoration",
        "Contact" : "9888821904",
        "Category" : "Decoration & Hardware",
        "City" : "Sangrur"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i parse it and show in listview in android app?

Comment: Your question should be "How to parse JSON in Android?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: there is a difference in format
[
    {
        "vehicleType": "excavator",
        "vehicleColor": "yellow",
        "fuel": "diesel",
        "approvedOperators":
        [
            {
                "name": "Greg Stark",
                "experiencePoints": 13
            },
            {
                "name": "Aarti Patel",
                "experiencePoints": 21
            },
            {
                "name": "Tarek Mizan",
                "experiencePoints": 9
            }
        ],
        "treadType": "plate chain"
    },
        "treadType": "wheel"
    }
]

Comment: You should learn to adapt the changes instead of yelling the structure is different. Read up the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON syntax of your receiving data conforms to the standard model you can parse JSON in android with one of the libraries already present in the `org.json` package (eg. `JSONArray` for arrays).

I'd suggest you take a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library ( my personal preference, there are of course many others) for it makes it easier to focus on your business logic and not occupy yourself with parsing JSON.